# Undeploy war by deleting file in jboss

Tags: java, jboss

I have deleted wars:
`...\jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\mywar.war`
`...\jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\deployments\mywar.war`
`...\jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\deploymentBackup\mywar.war`

and then run:
`.\bin\standalone.bat`

Jboss still sees the war files. Why? Where has he hiden it?

Comment: can you connect to the jboss-cli and then run "ls deployments". this should list all the deployed war archives on your jboss. 

then you can run "undeploy nam-of-deployed-war"

Comment: is it possible to check the path to deploymented wars from jboss GUI? I can't reach the `jboss-cli` but I can reach jboss GUI and there still see deployment war files but don't see their paths...

Comment: i'm not sure about that, sorry. How did you deploy your application? via your IDE? it might be, that you war files are deployed via the actual jboss deployment mechanism as well. try stopping your jboss, delete the standalone/data directory and restarting your server

Answer (score 2):

1. Stop JBoss and verify that it's not running.
2. Open the file `...\jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml` with a text editor.
3. At the bottom of the file you find the deployments section:

```xml
<deployments>
...
</deployments>
```

4. Remove the whole deployments section.
5. Save the file
6. Run JBoss